# How to plot bar graph for each month over counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe `df` as below:

```
Student_id   Date_of_exam(d/m/y)  Student_Performance
1            1/4/2020              Excellent
1            30/12/2019            Poor
1            26/12/2019            Medium
2            3/1/2021              Medium
2            10/1/2021             Poor
3            4/5/2020              Poor
3            22/8/2020             Excellent
```

How can I get the bar-graph with `x-axis` as month-year(eg: y-ticks: Dec 2019, Jan 2020, Feb 2020) and on `y-axis` - the total number of students (count) whose `Student_Performance` == `Poor`.

Please, do give any ideas, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: I'm new to python, not sure how to proceed, this is what I referred to but not getting it right ```df['Date_of_exam'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_exam'])

s = df.resample('M', on='Date_of_exam')[['Student_Performance'== 'Poor']].size()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the Below snippet is what you are looking for :

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("student_data.csv") #assuming the data is in the csv file

# get only month and year from datetime column (date of exam)
df['date_col'] = df['Date_of_exam(d/m/y)'].dt.to_period('M') 

# group by based on month and year after filtering poor graded students
data = df[df['Student_Performance']=='Poor'].groupby(['date_col']).size().reset_index(name
    = 'count')  

ax = sns.barplot(x="date_col", y="count", data=data) #plot using seaborn
```

output : [image]